# Docker container fails to connect to second container when running under Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two processes that I have containerised as container1 and container2. I would like to run both of these together using Docker Compose. container1 should connect to container2. This does not currently work and I cannot figure out the problem.

Some test scenarios I have tried...

Run container2 using Docker Compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  container2:
    image: container2
    ports:
      - "4003:4003"
```

Now run container1 source code from outside Docker and point to 127.0.0.1:4003 - connects ok.

Or run container2 as above; note the IP address, then run container1 also from Compose, referencing the IP directly - also connects ok:

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    image: container1
    environment:
      - HOST=172.18.0.2
      - PORT=4003
```

But when I place them both in the same `docker-compose.yml` file, container1 never connects to container2, but can ping it by name - what gives?

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    image: container1
    depends_on:
      - container2
    environment:
      - HOST=container2
      - PORT=4003
  container2:
    image: container2
    ports:
      - "4003:4003"
```

Edit: it appears that there is a problem with using the container alias, as this also works:

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    image: container1
    depends_on:
      - container2
    environment:
      - HOST=172.18.0.2
      - PORT=4003
  container2:
    image: container2
    ports:
      - "4003:4003"
```

A further piece of the puzzle: internally container2 is using `socat` to expose the port the app is listening on:

```
echo "Forking :::4001 onto 0.0.0.0:4003\n"
socat TCP-LISTEN:4003,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:4001
```

Seems that this doesn't work with the container alias for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

`depends_on` only set the order in which the containers start: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson

I think you need to include `links` as well: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    image: container1
    depends_on:
      - container2
    links:
      - container2
    environment:
      - HOST=container2
      - PORT=4003
  container2:
    image: container2
    ports:
      - "4003:4003"
```

also, from the docs:

> depends_on will not wait for [dependencies] to be “ready” before starting [the container] - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

It's likely that your container1 app is starting before container2 is really ready to have connections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re. using `wait-for-it.sh` - I have implemented this. But still no dice. Btw, the code retries connecting 10x with `sleep(5)` in between in any case. I can see from the log that container1 should be ready. Adding `links:` section has no effect either. I note from the example in the link you provided they do not add this either. I don't think it is required. I already tested this using a simple echo server to test more generally TCP connection from container1 - worked fine.